# Memory Allocation (Pointers and Stacks)

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, segmentation-fault

I've created a stack of pointers, which is being used to create a binary tree. While I can fill the stack with individual nodes, upon trying to allocate the top node's memory to a new node so I can create an actual tree, it segfaults. As an example:

```
TreeNode *c = new TreeNode;
c = stack.top(); //this segfaults
```

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how this works, but since both are of the same type, shouldn't c be able to equal the top of the stack? I've been stuck on this for hours now.

Comment: You just leaked memory in two short lines.

Comment: What is the type of the stack, how are you filling it?

Comment: The stack is using a template for type and I fill it by pushing the root node after assigning the root node some data. If you'd like me to put that up there, I will.

Comment: Judging by the point chris made, I'd say the debate you're having leading off the second paragraph is more of a foregone conclusion. Perhaps after a little more time with pointers it will be clearer what to (and not to) do.

Comment: Depending on the stack implementation, if the stack is empty, and you try to `top` it, it might be accessing a bogus pointer.

Comment: @BrandinJefferson Is there even a remote chance you can post the stack class? Methinks something wicked that-way goes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how pointers work in C++/C. They are just integer values that represent memory addresses. The `new` keyword assigns memory for a class and then calls the constructor for that class.

So from what you have written

```
TreeNode *c = new TreeNode;
```

Allocate a pointer for a Treenode. Then allocate the memory for a Treenode, call it's constructor and assign the address of this memory block to the pointer.

`c = stack.top(); //this segfaults`

Get the address/pointer value returned by the function call stack.top() and assign it to the variable c.

As chris said, even if your code had worked it is a leak as there is no garbage collector in c++ so when you do c= stack.top() the memory previously assigned is just lost on the heap.

Either

```
Treenode *c = new Treenode;
delete c;
c = stack.top();
```

Or

```
Treenode *c = stack.top();
```

Your observable problem is in the call to stack.top() somewhere. I'd suggest a pointer tutorial like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Pointers

Comment: Ah, that didn't work either, but thanks for the tutorial. God knows I need one.

Comment: @BrandinJefferson I think the tutorial it will probably help a ton. Starting in C-pointers is a shift from any prior language, Brandin, especially a garbage collected one. We've all done it so long its like breathing; automatic. take some time. its worth it.

Comment: The problem is in stack.top() or in the destruction of your stack at the end of the program, not in the code you posted. Have a crack at the tutorial.