# how to remove segmentation fault while deleting list of class pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have  two classes

```
class A{};

class B{
Private:
 list<A*> * mylist;
 remove();

};

void B:: remove() // To remove list mylist
{
  list<A*>::iterator iter = mylist->begin;
  for(;iter!=mylist->end;)
  {
    list<A*>::iterator iter1 = iter++;
    --iter;
    delete (*iter); 
    mylist->erase(iter);
    iter = iter1;
  }

}
```

I am getting segmentation fault in remove function , Please correct me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: For one thing, `mylist` appears to be uninitialized. Please post a complete, minimal sample program that demonstrates the problem. See http://ssccee.org for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code appears to wipe the list. That being said..

```
for (list<A*>::iterator it = mylist->begin();
   it != mylist->end(); delete *it++);

mylist->clear();
```

or did I miss something?

Comment: again getting segmenation fault if i write only `mylist->clear();` then i do not get any fault but in that case there remains memory leaks.

Comment: That means the pointers in the list are either already freed or garbage in the first place. I'd check how it is populated and make sure each item is still valid. any chance they're being delete'ed somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Never reinvent the wheel...

```
void B::remove()
{
    mylist.clear();
}
```

Comment: leaks every dynamic object in the list.

Comment: At what time is A* a smart pointer (I totally agree it *should* be, however =P)

Comment: @WhozCraig, I was just about to add that on :p Maybe this is enough to convince the OP to start using them.

Comment: Gotta tell ya chris, your posts crack me up sometimes. couple days ago the "you just leaked memory in two lines" comment about brought me to the floor I was laughing so hard. For ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575825/memory-allocation-pointers-and-stacks#comment16943727_12575825

Answer (score 0):

This program does not segfault and it runs successfully under valgrind:

```
#include <list>

class A{};

class B{
public:
  B() {
    mylist = new std::list<A*>;
    mylist->push_back(new A);
    mylist->push_back(new A);
  }
 ~B() { remove(); }

private:
 std::list<A*> * mylist;
 void remove();
};

void B:: remove() // To remove list mylist
{
  std::list<A*>::iterator iter = mylist->begin();
  for(;iter!=mylist->end();)
  {
    std::list<A*>::iterator iter1 = iter++;
    delete (*iter1); 
    mylist->erase(iter1);
  }
  delete mylist;
  mylist = 0;
}

int main () { B b; }
```

Nevertheless, I would be very upset if you wrote that program for me.

- It violates the rule of three.
- It `new`s  an `std::list`. Never `new` a standard container, it just wastes space.
- It holds naked pointers with confusing ownership semantics. Prefer `std::list<A>`. If you absolutely need pointers, use `std::list<std::shared_ptr<A> >`.
- It does not provide exception safety.

If you could modify your data structure, here is how I would write your program. Note the lack of explicit destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator. *Everything just works.*

```
#include <list>

class A{};

class B{
public:
  B() {
    mylist.push_back(A());
    mylist.push_back(A());
  }

private:
 std::list<A> mylist;
 void remove();
};

void B:: remove() // To remove list mylist
{
  mylist.clear();
}

int main () { B b; }
```